# Parallax effect: one div over another div?

Tags: html, css, parallax

My HTML code look like this:

```
<div id="a" class="panels">FIXED PANEL</div>
<div id="b" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 1</div>
<div id="c" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 2</div>
<div id="d" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 3</div>
```

I want the second `<div>` `b` to appear on top of the `<div>` `a`, and the `<div>` with `id` `d` to appear on top of `<div>` `c`. The two divisions are the same size, I tried to add `position:fixed` and `top:0` in the first `<div>` `id` but I don't get the effect I want, the first `<div>` is repeated every time a `<div>` goes on top. I know that this issue comes from `position:fixed` and I don't know how to fix it(to make the first `<div>` don't repeat after every scroll but to get the parallax effect for all divisions).

I made a demo with my issue: **http://jsfiddle.net/1g8sLnfk/5/**

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` instead of `position:fixed`

```css
html,body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background:black;
}

.panels {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#a{
  background-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg");    
  color:red;
  top:0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

#b{  
  background:yellow;
  top: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

#c{
   background:pink;
   top: 200vh;
   z-index: 3;
}

#d{  
  background:green;
  top: 300vh;
  z-index: 4;  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="a" class="panels">FIXED PANEL</div>
    <div id="b" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 1</div>
    <div id="c" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 2</div>
    <div id="d" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you,but i get the parallax effect only on the second div b,i want to be in leader,div c to be over div b ,etc. I want to make something like this:https://gispub.epa.gov/air/trendsreport/2019/#effects